# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser private browser C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, session, cookies, cefsharp

I want to use cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser to create my program.
In my program, when I click in "Load" button, ChromiumWebBrowser will load a website, and I will enter username and password to login.
When I click "Load" button again, I want ChromiumWebBrowser clears everything, include cookies, session,..., and reload the website.

In my code, when I click "Load" button, I disposed ChromiumWebBrowser instance and create new one

```
       private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctr in splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls)
            ctr.Dispose();
        CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser wb = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www........")
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(wb);
    }
```

But cookies, session...is not deleted. 
I tried command:

```
CefSharp.Cef.Shutdown();
```

But it also closed my program.
How to delete browsing data before load a new address? Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: You isolate instances of `ChomiumWebBrowser` using a `RequestContext`, by default a `Global RequestContext` is used. You can create a new one for each instance and they will be isolated. `browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext();`

Answer (score -1):

This code will clear all cookies
in WPF

**C#:**

```
class VkLogin : Window{
public VkLogin() {
    InitializeComponent();
    WebView.Address = "https://oauth.vk.com...";
    CefSharp.ICookieManager m = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
    m.DeleteCookies("", "");
}
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window>
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="WebView"/>
</Window>
```